# vscode shortcut key for making one edittor group bigger than others

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When having multiple editor groups, they take the same space in `VSCode`. For example, if I have 2 vertical groups, each one takes 50% of my screen. Now, if I double click on a file name in the group e.g. 2, this group takes about 70% of my screen and becomes bigger, so I can see the code better. If I double click again, both groups will be 50-50 again.

What is this feature called? What's the shortcut key for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called `Toggle Editor Group Sizes` And there is no `shortcut` by default, but You can set it as you like. I set my own shortcut (*Ctrl+Shift+Alt+9*) and tested it successfully.

*Tested with Ubuntu 20.04 and Visual Studio Code 1.64.0*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Warning: as explained by [Aymen Kharroubi](https://github.com/akharrou) in [issue 154068](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154068) "`View: toggle editor group sizes` doesn't work in a complex window layout"

Example:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36056254/177134820-10d87ee0-6414-435d-a997-11e8a94564b3.png]

> start in evenly distributed window layout (like in the image above), then run command "`View: toggle editor group sizes`", this works.
>
> Now run command "`View: toggle editor group sizes`", this doesn't work.
> Weirdly, if you move to some other window, some work, some don't

This has been fixed with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022, [PR 154467](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154467)) and is available today in [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).